# Migrating large SVN repo to Git failing Out of Memory Exception

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I am trying to do a git svn clone of a very large SVN repo. I have done earlier migrations using `git svn clone` with full branching, tags, and history maintained and all have gone well. 
But this time the script after running for quite some time throws an error:

`libsvn: Out of memory - terminating application.18 [main] perl 13884 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to perl.exe.stackdump`

I researched everywhere but couldn't find anything related to this. If somebody has encountered similar error I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Is this a one-time conversion and you are using only Git afterwards, or do you want to commit back to SVN from your Git clone?

Comment: This is a one time conversion and once things are moved to Git we will only use Git and stop using SVN

Answer (score 2):

`git-svn` is **not** the right tool for one-time conversions of repositories. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case and should not suffer from OOM error.

There are pleny tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` (or the wrong `svn2git` in your case) is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

There are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)